# Use of label Attribute in IE7+

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-select

As you know, for IE7+, label supresses the inner text of the option tag. Even using emulate meta tags in IE8 doesn't work. Is there a workaround that forces IE7+ to show the inner text, instead?

```
<option label="myLabel">myInnerText</option>
```

I have about a thousand screens having this kind of usage spread over the system, and I can't find a way to refactor it with just a replace (due to poor quality code).

Regards.

Comment: "This attribute allows authors to specify a shorter label for an option than the content of the OPTION element. When specified, user agents should use the value of this attribute rather than the content of the OPTION element as the option label." — why do you have a label attribute if you don't want the inner text suppressed?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use jQuery to do it,

```
$("option").attr("label", "");
```

but this raises the question: Why are you using an attribute that is specific to IE, only to want to remove it if the user is viewing your page in IE?

Comment: The point is that, the system used to support only IE6, so everything was based on that; there is a heavy JS usage, for example. Now, we are upgrading to IE8, and I want to touch the codes as few as I can.

Comment: OK.  So what do you have control over?  Why can't you just change the HMTL?  Are you looking for a JavaScript fix?

Comment: Because I have about a thousand screens having this kind of usage spread over the system, and there is not a way to refactor it with just a replace. ( Yes it's a bad code )

Comment: What kind of setup do you have?  Are you serving static HTML content or do you use servlets and view rendering technology (PHP, JSP, etc.)?  If you have server-side processing, your solution could be simpler than if you have thousands of static HTML pages.